# How to configure ckeditor for different toolbars?

Tags: wysiwyg

In D7 I would like to use ckeditor with a specific profile for a user role. The user is only allowed to use bulleted listed. How to do this?

I did the following:

- Configured in drupal a ckeditor profile call "builder"
- For a role say"Client" I added a text format say "Bullitsformat"
- for a field in a content type "testfield" I configures user can choose own filter.

If I test the edit form no toolbar is displayed when user selects Bullitsformat.

What to do?

Comment: How did you set up the "Bullitsformat" so that it would only allow bulleted lists?

Comment: Configured the HTML filter, only allow <ul> <li>

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to first add the bullitsformat and then edit the profile, so this profile is shown in the profile of the ckeditor.